# php strtotime error with sentence

Tags: php, date, strtotime

the `strtotime` section of this concatenated method does not work

`date("m/d/y", strtotime("last ".date("l")." of this ".date("F")))`

example

"last Monday of this June" , and this is exactly what the aforementioned string inside of `strtotime` translates to

Instead I get `"12/31/69"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove the `this`.

```
php > var_dump(date("m/d/y", strtotime("last ".date("l")." of ".date("F"))));
string(8) "06/25/13"
```

Or use `this month`

```
php > var_dump(date("m/d/y", strtotime("last ".date("l")." of this month")));
string(8) "06/25/13"
```

Comment: your solution worked, I thought strtotime needed that designation, or does it only use `last` and `next`

Comment: `this month` is not necessary as the date being manipulated by the relative statement is already this month (it is the current date and time); `last *dayname* of` would suffice.

Answer (score -2):

PHP does not accept relative months, such as `last June`. Units of time (`day`, `week`, `month`) and days of the week can be used in this way, but not names of months.

All available relative formats are documented on the [**Relative Formats**](http://php.net/datetime.formats.relative) manual page.

A valid format might look like:

```
last Monday of June
```

To dictate the year, a relative year statement may be used. For example,

```
last Monday of June last year
```

See:

- Relative Formats - http://php.net/datetime.formats.relative

Comment: `strtotime` understands `last June`

Comment: Not as a compound. Separately, it understands `last` (assumes `day`) and `June`.  » [Try for yourself](http://3v4l.org/5IpAm) `last June` simply sets the month to `June` (thus, the 1st day of June of the current year) then moves **one day back**.

Comment: P.S. *Please* be sure to read and absorb the linked manual page. It is there for a reason!